# plugins_loaded action is not working properly

Tags: plugins, php, actions, wp-mail

I am trying to send an email to the user after form submission but I get an error
`Call to undefined function wp_mail() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\contact form\contact-form-plugin.php on line 46`
I googled it and found that it has something to do with `add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'functionShowForm' );`.I added this line to my code but it shows another form above main form as shown here [link](http://prntscr.com/7skn4p)
what I am doing wrong here ?
My plugin file's code is

```
    <?php
    /*
    Plugin Name: Contact Form 
    Plugin URI: http://wpgeeks.net/
    Version: 1.0
    Author: 
    Description: 
    */

    /*Security Note: Consider blocking direct access to your plugin PHP files by adding the following line at the top of each of them, or be sure to refrain from executing sensitive standalone PHP code before calling any WordPress functions.*/
    defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );



    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'functionShowForm' );
    function functionShowForm($atts){

            $values = shortcode_atts(array(

        'color'=>'white'
    ),esc_html($atts));//updated here
    ?>

<form style="color:<?php echo $values['color'];?>;" action ="#" method="post">
Name:   <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="First Name">
Email:  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="someone@gmail.com">
Password:<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
}//function ends here

function process_wpse_194468(){
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST" and isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $to = sanitize_email($_POST["email"]);//updated here
    $subject = esc_html($_POST["name"]);//updated here
    $message = $_POST["password"];
    echo "Email " .$to;
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
}
}
//short code
add_shortcode('showform','functionShowForm');
add_action('init','process_wpse_194468');

?>
```

Comment: 1) Are you sure this spelling is correct-- `contact form\contact-forn-plugin.php`? 2) That is a weird looking plugin. Why are you wrapping functions in `HTML` like that?

Comment: sorry about that , spelling mistake , updated.Is this the wrong approach of mixing html and php ? please guide me :)

Comment: just updated the code please take a look now :)

Comment: form shows in the admin area too [link](http://prntscr.com/7skveb)

Comment: Mixing HTML and PHP is fine-- PHP is built for that. What is weird is the way you had HTML exposed in the main plugin file for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plugins_loaded` is going to load this form much too early, even if you weren't getting errors. The form is loading before the opening `<html` tags. You need to select better hooks for this-- `admin_notices` maybe, but it is hard to tell exactly what you want.

Second, you need to separate your handler:

```
function process_wpse_194468() {
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST" and isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $to = $_POST["email"];
    $subject = "Apple Computer";
    $message = $_POST["password"];
    echo "Email " .$to;
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
  }
}
add_action('init','process_wpse_194468');
```

[Third, validate that input!](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data)

Comment: My main problem is `Call to undefined function wp_mail() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\contact form\contact-form-plugin.php on line 46`

Comment: And I don't get that error with my changes. That may be the only problem you are concerned with, but the code is flawed in other ways too.

Comment: yes , now this error is fixed after I updated the code according to yours. Would you like to explain what 'add_action('init','process_wpse_194468');' line did ?

Comment: I moved the form processing to a later hook so that the appropriate files are loaded before you try to use `wp_mail`

Comment: `process_wpse_194468` is this built in wp function ?

Comment: No. Its not. The function definition is included in my answer!

Comment: thank you soo much man :) , I have only one problem now tried reading other answers did not help me. When I submit the form I want to get the values entered by user but `action="<?php echo ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"` does not work , `action="#"` not works and neither `action=""` 
any thoughts ?(I want to land on the same page)

Comment: Have you tried not using an action at all?

Comment: yes I have tried with no action field too , but did not work :/

Comment: I just asked [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/194486/submit-the-form-to-same-page) here since `stackexchange` is not going to allow a long discussion here